# "Copy" a pdf file from Server A to Server B by PHP

Tags: php, file, file-io

Currently I am using a Amazon Service Cloud storage to put PDF files.

It is not through FTP but using the class of that storage service ([the reference is here])[1](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation#getObject)

```
// save it into a file (write stream)
// var_dump("S3::getObject() to savefile.txt", $s3->getObject($bucketName, baseName($uploadFile), 'savefile.txt'));

// Or write it to a resource (write stream)
// var_dump("S3::getObject() to resource", $s3->getObject($bucketName, baseName($uploadFile), fopen('savefile.txt', 'wb')));
```

Currently I can obtain the binary code of a PDF file but how can I store it on the other server (Server B)?

```
foreach ($contents as $key => $value){
    if (strpos($key, 'pdf') !== false){
        if (($object = S3::getObject($bucket, $key)) !== false) {
            file_put_contents('path/'.$key, $object, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }
    }   
}
```

`$key` is the filename on Server B.

To be clear, the problem is: I have some binary code (which is a PDF file), how can I write the code into another file (= save as other PDF)?

Comment: How are you able to connect to the remote server? ftp/sftp?

Comment: the cloud services is not using the ftp connection.. i am using amazon s3

Comment: So you are moving the file from your local server TO s3?

Comment: yes Thanks I figure out how to save now

Comment: would be nice if you could share your solution with us.